# Find the form of $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ which is entire, conformal and $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, quasiconformal-maps

> Find the most general form of a function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ which is entire, conforal and $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=\infty$.

I know that if $f$ is entire and $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$ then $f$ is a polynomial. How can I use its conformity?

Comment: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Complex_analysis

Comment: Yes thanks. We know $f$ is a polynomial and its derivative a not zero anywhere. Thus $f$ must be of the form $ax+b$ where $a\ne 0$.

Comment: Is $z \mapsto z^2$ conformal at $z=0$ ? And about the limit at $\infty$ : $g(z) =z/f(1/z)$ is holomorphic on $|z|< r$ thus it is analytic, with a zero of order $m$ at $z=0$, which means $|f(z)| \sim C |z|^{m-1}$ from which we can show with Cauchy's integral formula that $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$  for $k > m-1$

Comment: @J.Doe exactly!